# Will SQL Server treat a USB 3.0 External Drive as local?

Tags: sql-server, usb-drive

I am a developer who keeps a local SQL Server instance on my laptop. We all do.  I am considering getting an external drive to keep backup files and the like.

In an earlier position, I used an eSATA-connected-drive which SQL Server would recognize as a **local drive** and thus allow direct backup and restore operations with it.   In that situation, SQL Server would *not* let a USB 2.0 drive be treated as local and would require that backup files on that drive be transferred to a local drive before restoring it *or* that backups would need to be done to a local drive and then copied manually to the external drive (a pain).

Well, time has marched on and I now have a nifty USB 3.0 port on my laptop.  My question is:

> Will SQL Server treat a USB-3.0-connected drive as local like it would
>   an eSATA drive or will it treat a USB 3.0 drive like a USB 2.0 drive and not allow it to
>   be used as a *local* drive?

Comment: I don't have one handy to test. Have you tried it?

Comment: Make sure the SQL service account has appropriate permissions to the drive. If the drive format is not NTFS, either format it to NTFS or backup to several files. The FAT format has single file size limitations. FAT32 has a max file size limit of 4 GB. FAT16 is 2 GB.

Comment: [NOTE: This was intended to be added to Aaron Bertrand's comment.] I am considering purchasing such an external disk.  I still could purchase an eSATA drive but that interface is a bit more of a hassle to use.  I am trying here to see if the USB 3.0 route would give me the same sort of ease-of-use before I lay my money down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbtrouble_e.html#partition).  Turns out it is the disk which reports itself as removable media or not.   Windows categorizes it accordingly.   Apparently, this has nothing to do with SQL Server except that at least some versions of SQL Server (2008 R2?) will only backup/restore to "local disks".

Answer (score 0):

I just used a USB 2.0 drive the other day to perform a restore to a test environment. I imagine that as long as Windows identifies the drive as a local disk and not removable storage, and the SQL Server service can access the directory, it should work just fine.